# Using the SSE protocol in Python Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, server-sent-events

I am trying to write a realtime web app which can respond real time messages updating in Flask framework. I am using code from http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/116/ but JavaScript EventSource SSE not firing in browser. From the log I can see I've published the data successfully but the webpage(http:xxxx:5000/) does not get updated at all.

```
import gevent
from gevent.wsgi import WSGIServer
from gevent.queue import Queue

from flask import Flask, Response

import time


# SSE "protocol" is described here: http://mzl.la/UPFyxY
class ServerSentEvent(object):

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.event = None
        self.id = None
        self.desc_map = {
            self.data : "data",
            self.event : "event",
            self.id : "id"
        }

    def encode(self):
        if not self.data:
            return ""
        lines = ["%s: %s" % (v, k) 
                 for k, v in self.desc_map.iteritems() if k]

        return "%s\n\n" % "\n".join(lines)

app = Flask(__name__)
subscriptions = []

# Client code consumes like this.
@app.route("/")
def index():
    debug_template = """
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
       <head>
       </head>
       <body>
         <h1>Server sent events</h1>
         <div id="event"></div>
         <script type="text/javascript">

         var eventOutputContainer = document.getElementById("event");
         var evtSrc = new EventSource("/subscribe");

         evtSrc.onmessage = function(e) {
             console.log(e.data);
             eventOutputContainer.innerHTML = e.data;
         };

         </script>
       </body>
     </html>
    """
    return(debug_template)

@app.route("/debug")
def debug():
    return "Currently %d subscriptions" % len(subscriptions)

@app.route("/publish")
def publish():
    #Dummy data - pick up from request for real data
    def notify():
        msg = str(time.time())
        for sub in subscriptions[:]:
            sub.put(msg)

    print 'data is ' + str(time.time())
    gevent.spawn(notify)

    return "OK"

@app.route("/subscribe")
def subscribe():
    def gen():
        q = Queue()
        subscriptions.append(q)
        try:
            while True:
                result = q.get()
                ev = ServerSentEvent(str(result))
                print 'str(result) is: ' + str(result)
                yield ev.encode()
        except GeneratorExit: # Or maybe use flask signals
            subscriptions.remove(q)

    return Response(gen(), mimetype="text/event-stream")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    server = WSGIServer(("", 5001), app)
    server.serve_forever()
    # Then visit http://localhost:5000 to subscribe 
    # and send messages by visiting http://localhost:5000/publish
```

Can you please shed some lights? I am testing with Chrome/34.0.1847.116. Thanks.